# getElementById javascript undefined

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, getelementbyid

I am currently working on this script for Greasemonkey. The goal of this script is to remove posts from specific users on the feed of the website MeetMe.com.
My code is:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        PostBeGone
// @namespace   TestingNameSpace
// @include     http://www.meetme.com/apps/home
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==
var posterId;
var blacklist = new Array();
var toDelete;
blacklist [0] = 45112400; //These are just random peoples' user Id's that I am
blacklist [1] = 9649820;  //using to test this script
blacklist [2] = 55907221;
blacklist [3] = 56788411;
window.onload = function checkAndRemove () {
    var children = document.getElementById('feedReloadArea').childnodes;
    alert(children); //alert says "undefined"
    i = 0;
    While (i < children.length) 
    {
        posterId = children[i].getAttribute('data-poster');
        toDelete = null;

        i2 = 0;
        while (i2 < blacklist.length)
        {
            if (posterId == blacklist[i2])
            {
                toDelete = children[i];
                break;
            }
            i2++;
        }
        if (toDelete != null)
        {
            toDelete.parentNode.removeChild(toDelete);
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Using various alerts with multiple executions, I know that the code executes up to the point where I have `alert(children)`, which is returning `undefined`.

Prior to having `window.onload =` in my script, in scouring Google and this website for answers, I read many places that the problem might be that the script could be trying to execute before the page was loaded, so I added the `window.onload =`. The problem persisted, however, and I can't find any questions similar enough to mine to make sense of it.

To see the html code for the elements, I've been using Firefox's "Inspect Element" feature. A snippet of the html code on the page that may help is:

```
<div id="feedReloadArea" style="display: block;">  
     <div class="feedItemArea feedSpotlightHighlight" data-comment-maintenance="0" data-created-at="1360098729.05091" data-numeric-reference-id="" data-reference-uuid="0d76957f-2f64-4654-99ea-f67974116b32" data-entity="StatusUpdate" data-poster="59538173" data-uuid="b9e85465-5b91-4b5c-a443-c4e37d716481"></div><div class="feedItemArea" data-comment-maintenance="0" data-created-at="1360103761.624714" data-numeric-reference-id="" data-reference-uuid="c2c201ca-a391-4fff-aec2-9823a3e90815" data-entity="StatusUpdate" data-poster="45508368" data-uuid="11149a32-38cf-4919-b081-0bd39bdc49eb"></div>
     <div class="feedItemArea" data-comment-maintenance="0" data-created-at="1360103737.756343" data-numeric-reference-id="" data-reference-uuid="997824a2-994c-467f-bfbe-aa4beb1e402f" data-entity="StatusUpdate" data-poster="38033716" data-uuid="bc075882-771c-4ee2-ad28-dbf21fbf3bd3"></div>
```

To clarify, that is only part of the HTML code. There are many of those classes on the feed, as each one represents one user's post. Also, each class has multiple within it, for things like the user's link and the user's profile picture. I, however, am wanting to remove full feedItemArea classes that have the same poster id as any that are on the blacklist.

I hope that I have been clear and concise enough to be easy to help, but if any other information is needed in order to help me, let me know and I will post it. My question is what is causing `children` to be `undefined`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `.childnodes` should be `.childNodes`. And note that not every child is an element node. If you only want element nodes, use `.children`.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is case-sensitive, and it's [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.childNodes) instead of `childnodes`. Btw, since you probably want to iterate element nodes only (no text nodes, comments, etc.), use the [`children` collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.children). Also, you hardly need the `window.onload`, since GreaseMonkey scripts are executed [on DOMready](http://wiki.greasespot.net/DOMContentLoaded) by default.

Comment: Also, thanks for the other tip as well. I am looking into it now.

Comment: If this answer worked for you (it should), please [tick the check-mark next to it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 1):

Capitalization!

```
var children = document.getElementById('feedReloadArea').childnNodes;
```